# Python, JSON, AJAX, JQuery + Jinja

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, python-3.x, jinja2

Имеется сайт, в котором я использую AJAX (через XHR запрос, XMLHttpRequest).
Сервер на пайтоне, на сервере (Python+Flask) генерится выборка из SQLной базы и возвращает через JSON дамп массив с энным количеством объектов внутри (`return json.dumps(hystorytable)` ),
ответ сервера:

```
[{"comment": "", "descr": "Salary", "p_id": 82, "quantity": 1, "summ": 21, "totalsum": null, "tranfere_date": "2017-05-04 17:58:34", "user_id": 3}, {"comment": "", "descr": "Salary", "p_id": 81, "quantity": 1, "summ": 2, "totalsum": null, "tranfere_date": "2017-05-04 17:57:41", "user_id": 3}]
```

Я хочу заменить свою табличку, которая ранее была сгенерена в HTML с помощью цикла Jinja на новую табличку, также сгенеренную с помощью Jinja цикла, но, видимо, Jinja не понимает отпарсенные данные (для генерации начальной таблицы используется `return render_template ("index.html", hystorytable=hystorytable)`).

JS-код такой:

```
var response = JSON.parse(aj.responseText);
$('#history_table').html('');
var insert_table='<table class="table table-striped"><thead><tr><th>Summ</th><th>Description</th><th>Comment</th><th>Date and time</th></tr></thead><tbody>{% for stock in response %}<tr align="center" ><td>{{stock.summ | usd}}</td><td>{{stock.descr}}</td><td>{{stock.comment}}</td><td>{{stock.tranfere_date  }}</td></tr>{% endfor %}</tbody></table>';
$('#history_table').html(insert_table);
```

Цикл Jinja, который генерит первоначальную таблицу (которую я хочу заменить сгенерированной новой таблицей), такой:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Summ</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Comment</th>
            <th>Date and time</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        {% for stock in hystorytable %}
            <tr align="center" >
              <td>{{stock.summ | usd}}</td><td>{{stock.descr}}</td><td>{{stock.comment}}</td><td>{{stock.tranfere_date  }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}

     </tbody>
</table>
```

Я сравниваю текст ответа, полученного при генерации страницы `render_template ("index.html", hystorytable=hystorytable)` - смотрю, что из себя представляет  hystorytable в питоне - print (hystorytable) с ответом, который получаю через return json.dumps(hystorytable)` (смотрю в JS в  responseText) и вижу, что  текст одинаковый, но результат получаю разный.

Помогите, пожалуйста, построить новую таблицу...

Comment: А новая таблица генерируется в коде с `var response = JSON.parse(aj.responseText);`? Т.е. вы делаете запрос через ajax, получаете в `response` тот json из сервера, но данные из `response` не используете, а подсовываете строку в `insert_table`, в которой есть шаблон Jinja, я правильно понял? :)

Comment: JSON я получаю до парса (если вывести куда-нибудь ответ сервера через aj.responseText, то я вижу приведенныq выше JSON). Если в хромоскую консоль засунуть JSON.parse ([{ ...]}), то консоль выдает ошибку Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: а саму таблицу я генерю в переменной здесь: var insert_table=...

Comment: На сервере возвращайте JSON через `from flask import jsonify` и `return jsonify(hystorytable)`. Тогда проблема с парсингом должна пройти

Comment: Этот вариант я тоже пробовал, результат - одинаковый.

Comment: Какой результат? Вы про таблицу или про ту ошибку с парсингом JSON, которую в консоли браузера видите?

Comment: И там и там - на веб страничке вместо создания цикла выводится текст цикла ({% for stock in sqlresponse %}{% endfor %}) и в колонки таблицы подставляется код дзинзя: {{stock.descr}} и т.д.. В консоли, если запусаю JSON.parse(_данные_из_aj.responseText_), тогда получаю ошибку VM699:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:21
(anonymous) @ VM698:1

Comment: 1. Если вы собираетесь через ajax обновлять данные, забудьте про Jinja. Jinja выполняется на стороне сервера и через `render_template` заменяет данные по шаблону. 2. Разберитесь почему происходит ошибки при парсинге в JS. Пока я не увидел что приходит с сервера, поэтому не могу сказать что не так

Comment: @gil9red 1) это - отличная идея! Спасибо за подсказку - я ж могу сгенерить новую страничку с помощью render_template и вставить ее через $('#history_table').html( )

Answer (score 0):

Огромнейшее спасибо gil9red за подсказку с полем поисков.

**Решение**

1) Создать в папке template файл table_operations.html

```
<div name="history_table" id="history_table">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Summ</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Comment</th>
                <th>Date and time</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            {% for stock in hystorytable %}
                <tr align="center" >
                  <td>{{stock.summ | usd}}</td><td>{{stock.descr}}</td><td>{{stock.comment}}</td><td>{{stock.tranfere_date  }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}

         </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

2) в питоне исправить код возврата:

```
return render_template ("table_operations.html", hystorytable=hystorytable)
```

3) в JavaScript внести исправления:

```
   $('#history_table').html(aj.responseText);
```

где history_table - это id моего дива, в котором находится таблица:

```
<div name="history_table" id="history_table">
...
</div>
```